# How can update custom meta for all posts

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, post-meta

How can update custom meta (likes) for all posts that have this meta?

If i used something like this:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, "likes", 1 );
```

it's required to add the post id that I need to update its meta.

Answer (score 2):

> How can update custom meta (likes) for all posts that have this meta?

**If you want to update every post that has this meta:**

See the [returns field parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter) and [custom field parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) for `Wp_Query` to 1) retrieve only posts with that `meta_key`, and 2) to lighten query and only return the `ids` instead of full objects. Then loop through them.

**Something like this (untested):**

```
$args = array( 'fields'          => 'ids', 
               'posts_per_page'  => -1, 
               'post_type'       => 'posts', 
               'meta_key'        => 'likes' 
               );
$all_ids = new WP_Query( $args );

foreach( $all_ids as $ai ) {

   update_post_meta( $ai->post->ID, 'likes', 1 );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this code for editing the meta_value of all postmeta with meta_key "background-video". I want to edit the existing value of all those, clearing every value. I have tried using your code, here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/300905/edit-postmeta-when-user-changes-user-role without any success!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this foreach loop to update all posts. using get_posts() function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
foreach($posts_array as $post_array)
{
    update_post_meta($post_array->ID, 'fb_likes_count', true);
}
```