# Edit postmeta when user changes user role?

Tags: php, customization

I'm trying to update a postmeta field in the database called background-video. I want to clear the value from this when a user has changed the role to a user role called basic.

I found this code, which from what I understand runs when a user has changed role to the user role "basic".

```
add_action( 'basic', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles ) 
{
    // Your code ...

}, 10, 3 );
```

The problem is I don't know how to target all the postmeta fields called background-video and clear the meta-value from them.

EDIT: I tried this, but it is not working:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles )
{
    if ( 'basic' == $role ) {


            $args = array( 'fields'          => 'ids',
                           'posts_per_page'  => -1,
                           'post_type'       => 'attachment',
                           'meta_key'        => 'background-video'
                           );
            $all_ids = new WP_Query( $args );

            foreach( $all_ids as $ai ) {

               update_post_meta( $ai->post->ID, 'background-video', '' );
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();


    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

Found the function here [How can update custom meta for all posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270036/how-can-update-custom-meta-for-all-posts)

One other thing is that I use this on a WP Multisite, and I let the users select from a few different roles, but I want this function to fire when they select "basic".

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not entirely correct. This code will run, when the action called `basic` will be called using `do_action('basic', ...)`. But... There is no such action in WP core, so your code won't run at all, I'm afraid.

There is hook that might be helpful in your case. It's called [`set_user_role`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/set_user_role) and it has 3 params (`$user_id`, `$role`, `$old_roles`).

So your code should look more like this:

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', function( $user_id, $role, $old_roles ) 
{
    if ( 'basic' == $role ) {
        // Your code ...
    }

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing! Great to know how that works. I tried the part to update the postmeta with empty meta_value, this way without success: update_post_meta( $post_id, 'background-video', '', $prev_value );

Comment: And what is $post_id? Is it defined anywhere in your function?

Comment: Post ID doesn't matter, I want to edit all meta_value (make them empty) from all meta_key called "background-video". So Post ID doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok. Stop. You can’t just make some wish how the function should work and hope that it will. The $post_id param of update_post_meta is required, so you have to put some ID of existing post in there...

Comment: But if I don't know the post ID before and want to target all meta_key background-video without knowing the post id?

Comment: Then you'll have to find the IDs. You can't put random params in functions and think they will work like you wish... It doesn't work that way... Sorry...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76091/discussion-between-jockebq-and-krzysiek-drozdz).

Comment: Updated my first post with new code, which may be close to the solution, but it doesn't work.